# submit form ajax, receive null value in controller

Tags: ajax, spring, null, form-submit

I'm submitting a form to a spring controller using ajax, but when it reaches my controller I'm getting a null model, here I'm adding my code:

```html
  

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#partsForm').submit(
  function(event) {
var str = $("#partsForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
 type : "POST",
 url : $("#partsForm").attr("action"),
 data : str,
 dataType: "json",
 contentType: "application/json"
});

return false;
  });
 });
</script>

<form:form id="partsForm" method="post" modelAttribute="modelpartsForm" class="form-horizontal" role="form"  action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/jsp/search/productConfig.html">
  <div class="form-group">
  <table class="table table-hover" width="50%" align="right">
    <thead>
      <tr>
      <th></th>
        <th>Part number</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Stock</th>
        <th>Qty</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <c:if test="${!empty partsForm.prodls}">
      <c:forEach items="${partsForm.prodls}" var="prodsByCat">
      <tr>
      <td></td>
       <td>${prodsByCat.partNumber} ${prodsByCat.description}</td>
       <td>${prodsByCat.price}</td> 
       <td>${prodsByCat.quantity}</td> 
      <td>
      <input type="NUMBER" MIN="0" MAX=${prodsByCat.quantity} STEP="2" VALUE="0" SIZE="3">
      </td>
 </tr>
      </c:forEach> 
       <tr>
      <td colspan="5">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">add parts</button>
      </td>
 </tr>
      </c:if>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
</form:form>
```

this is my controller

```js
 @RequestMapping(value="/productConfig",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 @ResponseBody
 public ModelAndView currentquote(@ModelAttribute("partsForm") PartsFormDTO partsForm) {
   ModelAndView modelView = new ModelAndView();
....do some logic
   return modelView;
 }
```

when debugging I'm only getting a null partsForm, should I change my ajax call? Thanks!.

Comment: You're trying to read an attribute from the model. Did you even create the "partsForm" attribute within your model before hitting that page? Before getting to the page with the Ajax call, you should add the attribute to the model. After the attribute will be set, I believe you'll be able to read from it on your Ajax calls.

Comment: Hello @MosheArad this is the model I'm using:

public class PartsFormDTO {
 private List<ProductDTO> prodls;

 public List<ProductDTO> getProdls() {
  return prodls;
 }

 public void setProdls(List<ProductDTO> prodls) {
  this.prodls = prodls;
 }
}

I'm naming my model "partsForm", this model contains a list of other objects "prods" as you can see in this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what the issue was, forgot to post the answer before, I wasn't actually submitting the model, since I have a list of products inside that model, I using varStatus="status" and passing them into the form, I'm passing them like hidden values,

```html
   <input type="hidden" name="prodls[${status.index}].partNumber" value="${prodsByCat.partNumber}"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="prodls[${status.index}].price" value="${prodsByCat.price}"/>
```

so that was first mistake, after that i was getting to my model, but instead of refreshing the DIV i wanted to update, it was redirecting me to the page view, so I had to modify my ajax call, like this:

```html
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#partsForm').submit(
  function(event) {
   var partsForm = "${partsForm}";

var str = $("#partsForm").serialize();
$.ajax({
 url : $("#partsForm").attr("action"),
 data : str,
 type : "POST",
 success : function(response) {
  $("#prodConfig").html(response);
 },
 error : function(xhr, status, error) {
  alert("ERROR:"+xhr.responseText);
 } 
});
```

After that it was getting to my controller and refreshing only the DIV I needed

Answer (score 0):

This is how you should pass attributes within your model:

Let's say that you want to load a page/request for a page, which has this URL: `http://localhost:8080/carApp/add`

Now, in order to tie to it an attribute within a model you should have a controller that knows to accept requests to the above-mentioned URL. which means you should have a controller with the next: `@RequestMapping(value="/add")`

Now, inside it, i can create a new object and tie it as an attribute to the model. like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add",method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String addCar(Model model){

    model.addAttribute("car", new Car());

    return "car_add";
}
```

This is just a preparation to try bind data to that car attribute.

In the above, you can see that whenever I'll GET request the /add route I'll attach a new Car object to the model, ***and you can use that Car object within your JSP file, with help of Expression Language*** in order to bind data to it.

Now, let's say that you filled out your JSP form with the intention to bind data to that Car attribute within your JSP file.

When you'll POST request that form to a controller, you'll be able to use `@ModelAttribute` on another method within your controller and actually do that binding. like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/add", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveCar(@ModelAttribute Car car){
    /*** some manipulation on car object ***/
    System.out.println("saving car");
    return "car_add";
}
```

That POST request will reach the saveCar method and will try to bind the original empty attribute value from the GET request to the car parameter with the POST request after you put data inside it on your JSP.

Comment: Thanks @MosheArad, but in my case I'm submitting a form that contains a model that has a list of other objects, and I want to see the results in a DIV in the same page, thats why I need an ajax call, right now I'm having problems on getting the model attribute containing the list of products, I'm getting an empty list in my controller

Comment: "but in my case, I'm submitting a form that contains a model that has a  list of other objects" --> before submitting that form, and even before loading that page with your form, you should prepare an empty "list of other objects". Then you can fill your form, submitting it, and only then the data suppose to be bind. pay close attention to the explanation above.